# Android/Java changing TextViews text by inputting String id's HELP!

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

Well as the title states, anytime I try (in my java class) to settext of a TextView by directing it set the text of a string listed in "strings.xml" my program crashes, If i remove that call then the program runs fine.  Below is an example.

```
    MediaPlayer dus;
String Stat;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView T = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Status);
    dus = MediaPlayer.create(DialUpDroidActivity.this, R.raw.dus);
    Timer timer;
    timer = new Timer();
    dus.start();
    Stat = getString(R.string.Dial);

    TimerTask TxtTimer = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            T.setText(Stat);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(TxtTimer, 7000);

}
```

So as you can see i tried to do T.setText(Stat); but the program crashed. I've tried T.setTextView(R.string.Dial); and T.setTextView("Hello") Both methods crashed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its good to go through docs once before ask .

Comment: I did... call me incompetent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initiliazed your textview?

```
TextView T = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```

Comment: Yes I have, the code that I posts was rewritten in after multiple ways of trying to do what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Where is

```
T = (TextView)findById(...)
```

?
Use

```
getString(R.string.XXX)
```